# Chrome extension causes browser to crash after setting "This can read and change site data" to "when you click the extension"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, crash

we are developing a chrome extension, but recently we found out, that when you right click the extension, go to "This can read and change site data" and pick the first option ("when you click the extension") this causes the browser to crash.

So far I really wasnt able to find any related question regarding this. Also the problem is that i have no idea how to debug this. I tried running chrome from terminal with verbose logging, but when the browser crashes, I only get this

`[1018/170905.295203:warning:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)`

Our extension is installed not from store but from url through group policy. I removed all the code from the extension, but the issue is still happening.

Our manifest looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "some name",
    "icons": {
        "16": "some-icon16x16.png",
        "48": "some-icon48x48.png",
        "128": "some-icon128x128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "some-icon128x128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "alarms",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources": ["somescript.js"]
}
```

Please any advice will be much appreciated, or maybe some helpful tip on how to debug this. Thanks

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, so you'll have to use a native debugger with symbol file to debug it, see Chromium's documentation. A much simpler method to debug it is to find the bad commit in chromium by [bisecting](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/). An even simpler method is to report the bug in https://crbug.com.